# Imported class is undefind in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, class, import, react-router

So I have these two classes

**App.js**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import APIController from './APIController';
import Beer from './Beer';
import "./App.css";

class App extends Component{
  state = { beers: [] };

  componentDidMount(){
    console.log(APIController.getAllBeers());
  }
  
  render(){
    return (
      <span className="App">
        {this.state.beers.map(beer => <Beer beer={beer} />)}

        <button>Add New Beer +</button>
      </span>
    )
  }
}

export default App;
```

**APIController.js**

```
class APIController {

  static getAllBeers() {
    fetch('/beers')
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(beers => { return beers });
  }
}

export default APIController;
```

Adding breakpoint on the `componentDidMount` method shows that `APIController` class is undefind and as a result prints `undefind` in the console. I don't understand what's wrong. Any ideas?

Comment: Since your `getAllBeers()` method is not returning anything it will print `undefined`

Comment: Oh, so the way I have this `{ return beers }` is not returning the beers it got from the API?

Comment: Yes. `return` inside `.then()` will work in async manner. Update my answer (need to change both the files code). Check if it works as expected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your components code as below

```
// App.js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import APIController from './APIController';
import Beer from './Beer';
import "./App.css";

class App extends Component {
  state = { beers: [] };

  componentDidMount() {
    // Read the data and set it to state
    APIController.getAllBeers().then(beers => this.setState({ beers }));
  }
  
  render() {
    return (
      <span className="App">
        {this.state.beers.map(beer => <Beer beer={beer} />)}
        <button>Add New Beer +</button>
      </span>
    )
  }
}

export default App;



// APIController.js
class APIController {

  static getAllBeers() {
    return fetch('/beers') // Add a return key word here
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(beers => beers);
  }
}

export default APIController;
```

Comment: There we go! Thank you. Javascript can get so confusing after years of Java and C#.

Answer (score 0):

Your static method `getAllBeers` doesn't return anything.
To fix this you can do the following:

```
static async getAllBeers() {
  let beers = await fetch('/beers');
  
  return beers.json();
}
```